# My simple sql update query is not working right :(

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I've got a simple sql query that is trying to update a single row. The code came from some Linq-to-sql code (i used Profiler to grab it), but please don't worry about the source (L2S) ... that's irrelivant to the question.

Now, when i try and do an update with the where clause, I get 0 rows updated.

I then try and do a `select` with the same `where clause`. i get a single result back. Ok, so the data is there.

It's only when i turn off some of the `where clause statements` does the query finally work. I just don't get it :(

I can't really explain it. So I made a video showing this.

Please watch the video on YouTube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ7GVpckfhQ).

Can anyone help? It's really weird :(

Database is MS-SQL 2008.

-- UPDATE

The sql i'm trying to execute (after i've cleaned it up from L2S)..

```
update tblBoardPost
    set IsSticky = 1
where IdBoardPost = 1278
    and IdAddress = 212787
    and Subject = N'ttreterte'
    and Banner is null
    and UniqueSubject = N'ttreterte5'
    AND (NOT ([IsAnnouncement] = 1)) 
    AND (NOT ([IsSticky] = 1)) 
    AND (NOT ([IsLocked] = 1)) 
    and IsVisible = 1
    and IdUserModified = 1
    AND [IdNewsArticle] IS NULL
    AND [IdList] IS NULL
```

(note: yes, i know the NOT (blah = 1)) is weird, but that's L2S that made that.

Update 2:

The code in the video is being ran in a transaction/rollback trans. this means that if i do run one of those weird scenario's that works, the change works .. but the rollback undoes it .. so when i run it a 2nd time .. the original value has been returned to the db row.

Also, in the vid, the select query is not exactly the same as the update query .. because i've been trying so many permutations (with no luck) .. so by the time i made the vid .. i forgot to show the original code. That said, the same code in both the select statement and the update/where statement (when i copy/paste on my machine) reproduces the exact same probs :(

Update 2 :)

As per Lieven's request, here's the screenshot showing the code and then the results.

[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7111/lieven.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7111/lieven.png)

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you are executing.

Comment: Done. Not sure if that helps. it looks pretty simple and i'm sure that data exists (check the video which shows that).

Comment: @ Niels - good idea re: the extra tag :)

Answer (score 0):

In the video, your select goes like

```
and not IsAnnouncement = 1
```

wich gives entirely different results as in your update

```
and not (IsAnnouncement = 1)
```

It seems you are suffering from an operator precedence issue .

**Edit**

as the queries don't match in your video and although you say they have matched could you copy paste following script and let us know if or if they do not give you the same results? (I for one would have a hard time believing that the rows affected would differ)

```
begin tran

select * 
from tblBoardPost      
where 
  IdBoardPost = 1278    
  and IdAddress = 212787    
  and Subject = N'ttreterte'    
  and Banner is null    
  and UniqueSubject = N'ttreterte5'    
  AND (NOT ([IsAnnouncement] = 1))     
  AND (NOT ([IsSticky] = 1))     
  AND (NOT ([IsLocked] = 1))     
  and IsVisible = 1    
  and IdUserModified = 1    
  AND [IdNewsArticle] IS NULL    
  AND [IdList] IS NULL

update tblBoardPost    
  set IsSticky = 1
where 
  IdBoardPost = 1278    
  and IdAddress = 212787    
  and Subject = N'ttreterte'    
  and Banner is null    
  and UniqueSubject = N'ttreterte5'    
  AND (NOT ([IsAnnouncement] = 1))     
  AND (NOT ([IsSticky] = 1))     
  AND (NOT ([IsLocked] = 1))     
  and IsVisible = 1    
  and IdUserModified = 1    
  AND [IdNewsArticle] IS NULL    
  AND [IdList] IS NULL

rollback tran
```

Comment: i've tried both. in fact, what was in the video was the code AFTER i tried the exact original code :(

i've also tried adding many brackets all over the place .. still no luck.

Comment: Side note: when marking some text as code, SO seems to remove all empty lines. Very annoying. Probably there's an easy way to fix this in my formatting. If anyone knows, please let me know.

Comment: Added image to opening post. First result is for the select statement. second result is the update (0 rows).

Comment: @Pure.Krome: I suggest you file a bug report with Microsoft. This obviously should not happen. As for your update, change it to update ... set ... where tblBoardPostUniqueID IN (select tblBoardPostUniqueID ...).

Comment: I can write a simple stored procedure that only updates the field with the where clause on the PK instead. That's fine .. but that sql above is generated by Linq-to-Sql .. so i'm not sure if i can change it?? Also, if i add a new bug report with MS Connect, i have no idea how they can reproduce it, etc. I feel like it's a wasted effort. Unless there's an MS Sql guy here who's interested in RD'ing into my box to see the error ... ???? Anyone here have some contacts?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: trust me, you don't want me giving advice on Linq-to-Sql. My skills in that area are a bit limited and that's saying much. As for the reproducability, all that might be required is a script for that one table with indexes and data.

Comment: if it's an index issue, is there anything I could do to check this? like .. disable all index's or something and then work back?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: anything is possible. If I would try to resolve it myself I would start with dropping all indexes one by one and trying the script after each index dropped and see if it makes a difference. If that's no help I would recreate the table in another database and try the script there. Try resolving it by eliminating every possible problem one by one until it works.

Comment: good idea Lieven :) i'll start by doing that. I'll script all my index's first, then drop and go step by step.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: If you ever find out what went wrong, I would be very interested as to what it was.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your video, and you should try the same SQL conditions, that you used to return one row in your select query, in your update query.  The conditions in the two SQL statements in your video aren't the same, and I don't really care why; they're not apples to apples.

Just copy and paste the working WHERE clause over the non-working one.

Comment: Originally, i did that. By the time i made the vid, i had some changes. But i swear when i use the same code, i get the same (bad) output :(

Comment: What indexes do you have?  Make sure you have an indexed identity field as the Primary Key, and try it again.  If that doesn't work, put a timestamp column in the table, and try it again.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz(VS.80).aspx for more information about how the timestamp is used.

Comment: i've got a number of index's on the query. The primary key does have a clustered index, with fill factor 80. It's 80% page fullness. 0% fragmented. I can grab a screenie if that helps?

Comment: Put a timestamp in the table, and let's see what Linq to SQL does with the SQL.  My guess is that it will drop every field in the WHERE clause except for the primary key and the timestamp.  The resulting query should work for your UPDATE.